# Bootstrap breadcrumb

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

How can I make the breadcrumb li-items to be within a div container? So, the breadcrumb is a div container-fluid (full-width) but the li-items is within a container so everything is aligned nicely (my nav items for example is within a container)?

I have tried to put

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<div class="container">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
</div>
</ol>
```

When I try this the li items just appears on top of each other... I can't figure out why putting a div container within it should work

Thanks alot in advance!

Jacob

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post what you've tried already? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, my first question. Yes, sure. So I have tried to put <div class="breadcrumb"><div class="container"><li><a href="#">Home</a><li><a href="#">Page1</a></li><li><a href="#">Page2</a></li></div></div>. When I try this the li items just appears on top of each other... I can't figure out why putting a div container within it should work

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and put the example code in there - makes it easier for people to read if it's all in the one place.

Comment: Sorry @jacobhed, it is not very clear what do you want to accomplish with that.
It may be much easier to stick to the bootstrap structures than to try to come out with some new tag combination. Then if you want to change how it looks, just add a custom css.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

As far as I know div element cannot be a direct child of list element. See here 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model

```
Permitted contents
Zero or more li elements
```